What are the pros and cons of using cherry-pick versus merge for release management?
What are the pros and cons of using cherry-pick versus merge for release management?
Background
We have a dev branch, and just created a release1 branch from it. Folks will commit relevant content to release1, and we'll need that content in dev for the next releases. The obvious solution (to me) is to git merge release1 to dev occasionally (completing the merge PRs with merge, not squash!).
However, most devs are used to cherry-picking their changes from release1 to dev. I tried to argue that using git merge will:

Keep track of which commits are merged, thus preventing us from forgetting commits in release1
Merge changes correctly, reducing merge conflicts, although I don't have a concrete example how that would happen.

One downside: If there's content that goes to release1 but doesn't need to go to dev - for example some temporary mock data - then we can just not cherry-pick it, while we can't skip it in merge.

see How do I explain ${something} to ${someone}?

Has your team given reasons why they use cherry-pick by default?

@PhilipKendall: The whole project has many long-term branches that do need cherry-picking between. So they're used to that and consider the resulting management overhead as inevitable. Also, there's a policy that PRs can't be merged, only squashed, though I can get that changed.

Before convincing devs to merge branches as a whole, you need to train them to put every commit into the branch (or maybe all branches) where they belong to.

@DocBrown: They already know where to commit. The problem is the back-merge.

Epilogue: Looks like I convinced them. They saw how easy the first merge was and were sold

Btw this is a question of culture. If you don't think in terms of "branches" but in terms of emailing patch-sets around, then cherry-picking is a completely natural way to do things. Git supports this, and even Linux is mostly developed like that. But a Git commit is not just a set of changes, but an immutable snapshot of a project state with all history leading up to that state. What I like about this is that I can split a large feature into multiple commits for easier review. I can write commits that depend on each other. I can add commit messages that explain the story of this code.

@amon It's indeed culture. But the culture here is one centrally-host repo (currently on github), and the tendency for cherry-picks comes from having multiple concurrent branches, itself coming from difficult-to-manage releases, coming from on-prem deployment at change-averse customers (healthcare).

@amon It’s not a question of culture. Merging is just better.  See gitworkflows(7): “Merges have many advantages, so we try to solve as many problems as possible with merges alone.” Also read “If you notice that” which is about how you can use cherry-pick if you made a mistake when you first committed some fix or something. Merging is the go-to technique for release management.

Merging provides a clearer and more complete picture of the changes leading up to each feature release or bug fix, making it easier for developers to trace back and understand why certain decisions were made. Cherry-picking can create fragmented or isolated commits, which makes tracking the development history and debugging more complex. It also increases the risk of human error, such as accidentally omitting commits, including those that other changes depend on. In practical terms, if you cherry-pick only some commits from a sequence with dependencies, you might end up with code that fails to compile, causes bugs, or doesn’t reflect the intended feature because the cherry-picked commits lack the full context. Merging, on the other hand, preserves the order and structure of dependent commits, reducing these risks.
If you are not using CI at the moment, and if you decide to go that way in future, merging is more CI-friendly. In my experience, CI tools (Jenkins springs to mind) handle branch merges much better than workflows that rely on individual cherry-picked commits, which are applied one-by-one to the target branch. Proper merging creates more stable integration points and enables smoother automation, both of which support reliable testing and deployment.
Merging is widely adopted as a best practice because it preserves commit history and dependencies, supporting a stable and predictable workflow. This also simplifies onboarding, as new team members are likely familiar with standard git workflows.
Finally, depending on how your company handles releases, merging provides the QA team with a consistent and complete set of changes. This makes test planning and execution more straightforward, reducing the risk of missing dependencies or introducing regressions. Unlike cherry-picking, merging allows QA to validate cohesive features or fixes in one go, minimising repeated testing and simplifying communication around what is included in each build. Additionally, merging enhances CI integration, making automated tests more reliable and reducing manual checks, so QA can focus on thorough testing rather than troubleshooting incomplete changes.

TLDR: never-ever cherry-pick or rebase in public.
